# Set JAVA_OPTS in JBOSS standalone.sh file

Tags: jboss, sh, java-opts

I have an app on jboss which logging through log4j. When I running my server through bat file (standalone.bat) logs work, but there is a problem under standalone.sh file. Here is how I set JAVA_OPTS in standalone.bat:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../standalone/configuration/log4j.xml"
```

and it works. How should I do this in standalone.sh file? I tried something like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS= "$JAVA_OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=file:$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/log4j.xml"
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using `standalone.conf` instead of `*.sh`? Add your custom entries at the end of *.conf file. Something like `JAVA_OPTS= "$JAVA_OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=file:../standalone/configuration/log4j.xml"` should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

The standalone.sh file will be interpreted by the shell, so it needs to be valid shell script. Remove the space after the `=` and you should be good. That makes the java opts line look like:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dlog4j.configuration=file:$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/log4j.xml"
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `JAVA_OPTS=` line to standalone.conf (as Pawel mentioned) seems to work great.  Then run standalone.sh as usual.  You should see your JAVA_OPTS listed in the boot-up message.