# Use Environment Variables in Standalone.xml for WildFly application on Linux VM

Tags: java, linux, jboss, environment-variables, wildfly

I am having trouble getting environment variables to resolve On a Linux VM when I start up a WildFly java application.

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.manager" value="org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"/>
        <property name="appname.url" value="https://${env.Environment}/appname"/>
</system-properties>
```

When I echo that environment variable (defined in /etc/environment) I get the following:

```
[ ~ ]$ echo $Environment
tst
```

I've tried updating the standalone.xml to have this these two properties set to true:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>true</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
```

Also tried updating bin/jboss-cli.xml with this setting set to true:

```
<resolve-parameter-values>true</resolve-parameter-values>
```

Starting the application using it's service (i.e., systemctl restart appname) throws errors in the logs like this:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("system-property" => "appname.url")]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression 'https://${env.Environment}/appname'"
```

Unfortunately, this does not resolve my issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I use wildfly for tests but not that well. There is no coherence with /etc/environment , take a look at this, it is simple  enough, the form you use required ./standalone.sh to set environment. http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-configuration/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-standalone-xml-or-host-xml/?amp=1

Comment: @SamuelMarchant - I tried that ./standalone.sh -DEnvironment=Environment and it worked! However, I need to make sure that this works for launching from a service at the server level and not just from this shell script. Do you know how that could work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957725/set-java-opts-in-jboss-standalone-sh-file.  And read the version getting sorted guide on their site. JAVA_OPTS is an environment variable used/usable in all Java startup command lines particularly servers of any make.

Comment: "systemd" service.  (ignore the posters question  reason).   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907443/wildfly-as-systemd-service

Comment: AFAIK -D java switch enables debug in the JVM so consequently no good for running under typical use.

Comment: This gives a good idea of what can be wrong in MS Win on a restart for a SERVICE.    https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/symantec-security-software/identity-security/identity-governance/14-4/installing/configure-wildfly-as-a-windows-service.html

Comment: @SamuelMarchant you got me most of the way there! Will post the answer that worked for me. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @ Stan  Gets tangled in web server configuration, glad to have known something of how from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this involved a few steps to get environment variables recognized by the WildFly app's service. It isn't exactly an environment variable, it's the closest you can get. Per [this thread on stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/how-to-make-unix-service-see-environment-variables), service strips all environment variables, so they cannot be referenced. Therefore, you must create a file that stores those variables and then source it in startup.

Here they are:

1. Update `bin/standalone.conf` with a new line to include `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Denv.Environment=$Environment"`
2. Create `/etc/default/appname` file so it can be sourced later on. That file only contains the line `Environment=tst`
3. Update `/etc/init.d/appname` file with

   ```bash
   [ -f /etc/default/appname ] && . /etc/default/appname
   export Environment
   ```
4. reload systemctl's daemon `systemctl daemon-reload`
5. restart the service `systemctl restart appname`